# How to find all subsets from an array that all elements in the subset that their absolute value of mutual subtraction is smaller than 8 in python?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have an array or list like {17, 24, 25, 33, 38, 42, 50}. How to find all subsets from the array or list that all elements in the subset that their absolute value of mutual subtraction is smaller than 8? For example, {17, 24, 25}, {38, 42}, {42, 50} are correct subsets because all elements in the subset their absolute value of mutual subtraction is smaller than 8,  but {17, 24,25,33} is not because |33 -17| is bigger than 8.

Answer (score 1):

If we sort the array first, then we can establish a sliding-window-esque style. Depending on the actual distribution of the data, this takes up to quadratic time to enumerate.

```
def subsets(l, max_diff):
    sorted_list = sorted(l)
    for i, low in enumerate(sorted_list):
        for j, high in enumerate(sorted_list[i:], start=i+1):
            if high - low > max_diff:
                break
            yield sorted_list[i:j]
```

Note that max_diff here should be 7 if you wish to set 8 as the cutoff.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, how do you print the generator? I tried  'Mat = subsets(list, maxdiff)
print([n for n in Mat])' , The result seems not correct.

Comment: Can you provide what you expect and what the code is providing?

Comment: Sure, for example, if my list is {17, 24, 25, 33, 38, 42, 50}, I would like to see the results like  {17,24,25}, {25,33}, {33,38},{38,42}, {42,50}.

Comment: {17, 24} also satisfies your requirement. Do you mean that you want the maximal one?

Comment: Yes, the maximum one.